# Cordova outgoing requests proxy handler

Tags: javascript, cordova, proxy, cross-platform, handler

I am developing Cordova as WUP and I need a kind of handler that will be as my proxy on all outgoing requests ( href/ajax/src etc...) .

In my app I am using JavaScript without angular, jquery or other libraries.
I've tried various ways to implement it by my self - no success.

Is there any plugins/libraries that can be used as a proxy?
Any ideas on how it can be manually implemented?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by proxy? If you're just trying to intercept HTTP calls, look at Angular's [$http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: OK, thanks... But I am not using angular in my application - I am using JavaScript with JQuery. I found jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()  function that helped me